# How do I replace 'bad characters' in a text file with a space in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to rid a text file of currupt data. I parse the file and if I find a bad character, I replace it with a space. My problem is that the space is not overwriting the bad character. Instead, the space is written on line 10 position 27. What's going on here?
I've been stuck on this seemingly simple problem for half a day. Thanks.

```
     Sub replaceChars(fname As String)
        Dim fs As New FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim r As New StreamReader(fs)
        Dim w As New StreamWriter(fs)
        Dim iChar As Integer = 0

        Do Until r.Peek() = -1
          iChar = r.Read()
          If iChar < 32 Or iChar > 126 Then
            If iChar = 13 Or iChar = 10 Then  'cr/lf, continue.
              Continue Do
            Else 'found a bad char. replace it.
              w.Write(Chr(32))
              w.Flush()
              fs.Flush()
            End If
          Else
            Continue Do
          End If
        Loop
        w.Close()
        fs.Close()
      End Sub
```

Comment: FileStream uses a buffer, 4096 bytes by default.  The first write will be made to offset 4096, not where you hope it will go.  You cannot make FileStream.Seek() reliable for a text file.  Write everything to *another* file, File.Replace() after you're done.

Comment: Thanks! I converted the lines to char arrays and replaced values in the array. then converted char array back to string. as you suggested, i used a temp file to write to and then copied contents from temp to real file. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont like the idea that you share a filestream for a reader and a writter, since I have had lots of 'unreasonable' problems because of that.

I've leanred that when using a Idiposable objects use 'Using' Statement wich waranties that proceses is finished, and you are not getting wired errors.

try this, maybe it helps and it is always better to do it this way.

[Using Statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter-vbnet)

Comment: Thanks. as you suggested, I seperated the reader and writer filestreams. and I use the using statement on the writer. it's working now.